# django 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, json, django

Sorry for my English. I have some data from another server, but I need to output this data like JSON.

if i print **response** in console:

```
{
    'responseStatus': {
        'status': [],
    },
    'modelYear': [
        1981,
        1982
      
    ]
}
```

but, if i return this **response** like `HttpResponse` i have an error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

this my code:

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', response, ensure_ascii=False)
return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

**UPD:**

I tried with this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_view(request):
    ...
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

but have error:

> Object of type 'ModelYears' is not JSON serializable

**UPD:**

I did like this:

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_view(request):
        ...
        return JsonResponse(json.loads(response))
```

but have error:

```
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'ModelYears'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) says the following about the `serializers` framework:

> Django’s serialization framework provides a mechanism for “translating” Django models into other formats.

The error indicates that your variable `response` is a `string` and not an Django model object. The string seems to be valid `JSON` so you could use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

# View
return JsonResponse(json.loads(response))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did like you say, but i have error `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'ModelYears'` i updated question

Comment: It seems I was wrong by assuming the type was a `string`. How did you create the `response` variable?

Comment: i use [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/) library for xml request. My `response` i create like this `response = client.service.getModelYears(accountInfo=account_info)`

Comment: I see, sadly I don't have experience with that library so I don't know what the type of your `response` variable. Maybe you can find that somewhere in documentation and see if there is a way to go from that to `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_view(request):
    ...
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Instead of serializing and sending it via httpresponse.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i did like you say but have error `Object of type 'ModelYears' is not JSON serializable` i update question

Answer (score 0):

This works for python 3.6 and Django 2.0

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
import requests

@login_required()
def get_some_items(request):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Token uydsajbkdn3kh2gj32k432hjgv4h32bhmf"}
    host = "https://site/api/items"

    response = requests.get(host, headers=headers)
    result = JsonResponse(response.json())

    return HttpResponse(result, content_type='application/json')
```